# installing an XML Websevice on Windows7 home basic

Tags: web-services, windows-7, iis-7

i've searched the site for this answer but couldnt find a good answer.

My client has a computer with Windows7 Home Basic Installed in his workstation (Thank you HP). 
and i need to install a web service on IIS. Web service is written in c# (.asmx). When i installed IIS into that windows, i've realized that there is no IIS comsole available in windows7 home basic machines.

is there a way to register web service from the command prompt? this web service is a middleware for communication several mobile devices with the sql server on the machine so it has to be able to connect form outer ip's too.

I've tried IISExpress but it only lets connectiong from localhost.

I cannot format his harddisk, also my client doesnt really want an edition upgrade.

Thanks for spending your time.

Comment: How much work would it be for you to rewrite the legacy web service as a WCF service, and then either self-host in a console app or via a Windows Service?

Comment: i really dont have time to rewrite the code, also i really dont want to put more effort on this project anymore. it has been tested and working on over 50 clients, so i dont want to rewrite all the code again just for 1 customer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a quick google search on hosting a web service (*.asmx) without IIS, and found this article:  [Run ASMX Without IIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163879.aspx).  A quick glance at it looks like you'd wind up writing your own host and implementing your own web server.

If this is the only solution available, I think you'd be far better off to rewrite your ASMX web service as a WCF web service, and then either self-host it or host it in a Windows Service.

Comment: i've never thought that i can run asmx without IIS. thank you so much, i've managed to install "Ultidev Cassini Web Server" and succesfully installed my asmx service. BTW: its a freeware opensource web server, i found it is much easier to understand and manage than iis control panel.